# comparing two arrays with different elements and location of elements

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have a list that is saved in arraylist.txt file.

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

I need to read the text file and make it as an array.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim arrServiceList
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\TestStatus\arraylist.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
  arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , "")
  Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrServiceList)
    WScript.Echo "Service: " & arrServiceList(i)
  Next
Loop
```

Then I have another array that need to compare:

```
A2
A3
A4
A5
A1
```

I need to compare both arrays and prompt the user if there are differences.

```
Dim i 'As Integer
Dim j 'As Integer
Dim isFound 'As Boolean

For i = 0 To UBound(tempArr) - 1
  isFound = False
  For j = 0 To UBound(arrServiceList) - 1
    If tempArr(i) = arrServiceList(j) Then
      isFound = True
    End If
  Next 'j
  If Not isFound Then
    MsgBox  tempArr & "not found"
  End If
Next 'i
```

But the output all not found.
The result should be A5 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I need to read the text file and make it as an array.

Utilise [`ReDim` Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17(v=vs.84).aspx) as follows; note that you need to use the [`Dim` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0(v=vs.84).aspx) with empty parentheses to declare a dynamic array  as `Dim arrServiceList()`. After declaring a dynamic array, use the `ReDim` statement within `Do Until` loop to define the number of elements in the array:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim arrServiceList(), objFSO, objTextFile, strNextLine, i
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\TestStatus\arraylist.txt", ForReading)

i = 0
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
  ' omit empty lines
  If Trim( strNextLine) <> "" Then
    ReDim Preserve arrServiceList( i)
    arrServiceList( i) = Trim( strNextLine)
    i = i + 1
  End If
Loop
objTextFile.Close
```

### I need to compare both arrays.

1. `UBound()` function *returns the **largest available subscript** for the indicated dimension of an array.* Hence, iterate from `0` to `UBound(someArr)`
2. Iterate `arrServiceList` array first (outer iteration).

The following code snippet should give proper result. It iterates "bigger" array first (outer iteration):

```
Option Explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim tempArr
tempArr = Split("A1 A2 A3 A4") ' default delimiter = space
Dim arrServiceList
arrServiceList = Split("A2 A3 A4 A5 A1") ' default delimiter = space

Dim i 'As Integer
Dim j 'As Integer
Dim ArrBig, ArrLes
If UBound(tempArr) > UBound(arrServiceList) Then
  ArrBig = tempArr
  ArrLes = arrServiceList
Else
  ArrBig = arrServiceList
  ArrLes = tempArr
End If
Dim isFound 'As Boolean
For i = 0 To UBound(arrBig)     ''' - 1
    isFound = False
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrLes) ''' - 1
        If arrBig(i) = arrLes(j) Then
            isFound = True
        End If
    Next 'j
    If Not isFound Then
        strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & arrBig(i) & " not found"
    End If
Next 'i

Wscript.Echo strResult
```

**Output**

```
==> cscript //nologo D:\VB_scripts\SO\q44533806.vbs
q44533806.vbs
A5 not found

==>
```

**Edit #2**: universal solution

```
Option Explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim tempArr
tempArr = Split("A1 A9 A3 A4 A6") ' default delimiter = space
Dim arrServiceList
arrServiceList = Split("A2 A8 A4 A5 A1") ' default delimiter = space

CompareArrays "arrServiceList", tempArr       , arrServiceList
CompareArrays "tempArr"       , arrServiceList, tempArr

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Sub CompareArrays( strArrName, ByRef ArrBig,  ByRef ArrLes)
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine _
            & "items not found in " & strArrName
  Dim i, j, isFound
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrBig)
      isFound = False
      For j = 0 To UBound(arrLes)
          If arrBig(i) = arrLes(j) Then 
              isFound = True
              Exit For          'j'
          End If
      Next 'j
      If Not isFound Then
          strResult = strResult & vbNewLine _
            & arrBig(i) ' & " not found in " & strArrName 
      End If
  Next 'i
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
==> cscript //NOLOGO D:\VB_scripts\SO\q44533806b.vbs
q44533806b.vbs
items not found in arrServiceList
A9
A3
A6
items not found in tempArr
A2
A8
A5

==>
```

Comment: i ve already tried your solution, still same the output, : the output all not found. then i noticed when i using msgbox join for arrservicelist, it only show A4 only. where  messed up when read in txt file?

Comment: how about if the tempArr only have A1,A2,A3 elements and arrserviceList have A1,A2,A4 eleemnts? How can i detect that there is element A3 that not exist in arrServicelist?