# read text file and make it in array - vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have a list that is saved in arraylist.txt file

```
-blank-
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

then i need to read the text file, split it and have an array consist if the value of text file.

```
 Const ForReading = 1
Dim arrServiceList
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\TestStatus\arraylist.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
  arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , "")
  Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrServiceList)
    WScript.Echo "Service: " & arrServiceList(i)
  Next
Loop
```

This is what I do to read and split the content of file. But when I try:

```
msgbox arrServiceList(0)
```

It prompt A4. Is it supposed to be -blank-? Then when I try to:

```
msgbox arrServiceList(1)
```

Error:

> Error: subscript out of range.

Please help.

Comment: as your code you must see that error...you have one for for read from file...When read one line THEN try to access `arrServiceList`...`arrServiceList` have no item or only 1 item and you try to access `arrServiceList(1)` then see that error

Comment: try to write 2 separate `for`...1 for read from file and one for loop on `arrServiceList`

Comment: In your split statement, you have used an empty string as a delimiter(""). Why? May be you should post the exact contents of your text file so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44533806/603855) your input file had no blank first line. So fire the idiot who put it there.

@JosefZ told you that VBScript arrays count from Zero to UBound()/Last Index. So **read** answers carefully.

```
>> s = "splitting a string on the empty string """" gives an one elm array containg that string"
>> a = Split(s, "")
>> WScript.Echo LBound(a), UBound(a), a(0)
>>
0 0 splitting a string on the empty string "" gives an one elm array containg that string
```

So after the loop, your array of size 1/UBound 0 contained the last line of your file. Trying to access the **second** element/index 1 caused the error.

To read a one-column file into an array, use ReadAll() and Split() on the EOL delimiter. As in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim s : s = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(".\44581406.txt").ReadAll()
WScript.Echo s
WScript.Echo "------------"
Dim a : a = Split(s, vbCrLf)
WScript.Echo Join(a, "<>")
```

output:

```
cscript 44581406.vbs
A1
A2
A3
```

Look at the output carefully - do you see the problem/draw-back of the SplitOnReadAll approach?

Use the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84).aspx) to make sure that you understand the concepts, objects, and methods.

Comment: Mystery down voter, have some decency to justify your action.